# "Update Terminated" on /nva01 transaction

Tags: abap, sap-erp

While running the SAP-SD benchmarking process on 3 tier SAP setup, a number of transactions are fired by automated users.
The following steps are executed,

```
6  /nva01             (Create Sales Order)
    [ENTER]

7  Order Type           or
    Sales Organization   0001
    Distribution Channel 01
    Division             01
    [ENTER]

8  Sold-to party        sdd00000
    PO Number            perf500
    Req.deliv.date       22.12.2009
    Deliver.Plant        0001

    Material         Order quantity
    sd000000         1
    sd000001         1
    sd000002         1
    sd000003         1
    sd000004         1
    [F11] (Save)

9  [F3] (Back)
    (This dialogstep is needed only to get 4 dialogsteps for VA01 as defined
     for the SD benchmarks)
```

whenever [F11] is pressed after entering information, it saves successfully. However, when [F3] is pressed, it shows error “unable to update”

Then I manually tried to execute the same steps

```
6  /nva01             (Create Sales Order)
    [ENTER]

7  Order Type           or
    Sales Organization   0001
    Distribution Channel 01
    Division             01
    [ENTER]

8  Sold-to party        sdd00000
    PO Number            perf500
    Req.deliv.date       22.12.2009
    Deliver.Plant        0001

    Material         Order quantity
    sd000000         1
    sd000001         1
    sd000002         1
    sd000003         1
    sd000004         1
```

[image]

On pressing [F11] it successfully saves. But when [F3] is pressed to go back to previous screen, it gives “update was terminated” error.

```
  [F11] (Save)
9  [F3] (Back)
```

[image]

Then to locate the root cause of error, SM13 transaction and it shows the following details for the error
[image]

There is a large number of same errors in logs, and the update key for all the error entries is the same “4A08B4400C022793E10000000FD5F53D” is this normal..?

On googling found out that the possible reason for this error could be

1. Key already exists in table and duplicate entry is disallowed.
   Which table is affected by this transaction..? how to resolve..?
2. Document number ranges issue
   Which document number range to modify..? how to resolve..?

Kindly advise how to resolve this

edit including system log--

> Runtime Errors         SAPSQL_ARRAY_INSERT_DUPREC Exception
> CX_SY_OPEN_SQL_DB Date and Time          12.05.2009 06:59:27
>
> ---
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |Short text
> | |    The ABAP/4 Open SQL array insert results in duplicate database
> records.                       |
>
> ---
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |What happened?
> | |    Error in the ABAP Application Program
> | |
> | |    The current ABAP program "SAPLV05I" had to be terminated
> because it has                       | |    come across a statement
> that unfortunately cannot be executed.
> |
>
> ---
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |What can you do?
> | |    Note down which actions and inputs caused the error.
> | |
> | |
> | |    To process the problem further, contact you SAP system
> | |    administrator.
> | |
> | |    Using Transaction ST22 for ABAP Dump Analysis, you can look
> | |    at and manage termination messages, and you can also
> | |    keep them for a long time.
> |
>
> ---
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |Error analysis
> | |    An exception occurred that is explained in detail below.
> | |    The exception, which is assigned to class 'CX_SY_OPEN_SQL_DB',
> was not caught                 | |     in
> | |    procedure "SD_PARTNER_UPDATE" "(FUNCTION)", nor was it
> propagated by a RAISING                | |     clause.
> | |    Since the caller of the procedure could not have anticipated
> that the                         | |    exception would occur, the
> current program is terminated.                                     | |
> The reason for the exception is:
> | |    If you use an ABAP/4 Open SQL array insert to insert a record
> in                              | |    the database and that record
> already exists with the same key,                                | |
> this results in a termination.
> | |
> | |    (With an ABAP/4 Open SQL single record insert in the same error
> | |    situation, processing does not terminate, but SY-SUBRC is set
> to 4.)                          |
>
> ---
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |How to correct the error
> | |    Use an ABAP/4 Open SQL array insert only if you are sure that
> none of                         | |    the records passed already
> exists in the database.                                            | |
> | |    If the error occures in a non-modified SAP program, you may be
> able to                        | |    find an interim solution in an
> SAP Note.                                                      | |
> If you have access to SAP Notes, carry out a search with the following
> | |    keywords:
> | |
> | |    "SAPSQL_ARRAY_INSERT_DUPREC" "CX_SY_OPEN_SQL_DB"
> | |    "SAPLV05I" or "LV05IU15"
> | |    "SD_PARTNER_UPDATE"
> | |
> | |    If you cannot solve the problem yourself and want to send an
> error                            | |    notification to SAP, include
> the following information:                                       | |
> | |    1. The description of the current problem (short dump)
> | |
> | |       To save the description, choose "System->List->Save->Local
> File                            | |    (Unconverted)".
> | |
> | |    2. Corresponding system log
> | |
> | |       Display the system log by calling transaction SM21.
> | |       Restrict the time interval to 10 minutes before and five
> minutes                           | |    after the short dump. Then
> choose "System->List->Save->Local File                             | |
> (Unconverted)".
> | |
> | |    3. If the problem occurs in a problem of your own or a modified
> SAP                           | |    program: The source code of the
> program                                                       | |
> In the editor, choose "Utilities->More
> | |    Utilities->Upload/Download->Download".
> | |
> | |    4. Details about the conditions under which the error occurred
> or which                       | |    actions and input led to the
> error.                                                           | |
> | |    The exception must either be prevented, caught within proedure
> | |    "SD_PARTNER_UPDATE" "(FUNCTION)", or its possible occurrence
> must be declared                 | |     in the
> | |    RAISING clause of the procedure.
> | |    To prevent the exception, note the following:
> |
>
> ---
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |System environment
> | |    SAP-Release 701
> | |
> | |    Application server... "hpvm-202"
> | |    Network address...... "15.213.245.61"
> | |    Operating system..... "HP-UX"
> | |    Release.............. "B.11.31"
> | |    Hardware type........ "ia64"
> | |    Character length.... 16 Bits
> | |    Pointer length....... 64 Bits
> | |    Work process number.. 10
> | |    Shortdump setting.... "full"
> | |
> | |    Database server... "ghoul3"
> | |    Database type..... "ORACLE"
> | |    Database name..... "E64"
> | |    Database user ID.. "SAPSR3"
> | |
> | |    Terminal.......... "hpvmmsa"
> | |
> | |    Char.set.... "C"
> | |
> | |    SAP kernel....... 701
> | |    created (date)... "Feb 24 2009 21:53:01"
> | |    create on........ "HP-UX B.11.23 U ia64"
> | |    Database version. "OCI_102 (10.2.0.4.0) "
> | |
> | |    Patch level. 32
> | |    Patch text.. " "
> | |
> | |    Database............. "ORACLE 9.2.0.*.*, ORACLE 10.1.0.*.*,
> ORACLE 10.2.0.*.*"                | |    SAP database version. 701
> | |    Operating system..... "HP-UX B.11"
> | |
> | |    Memory consumption
> | |    Roll.... 2013408
> | |    EM...... 0
> | |    Heap.... 0
> | |    Page.... 0
> | |    MM Used. 1966160
> | |    MM Free. 24336
> |
>
> ---
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |User and Transaction
> | |
> | |    Client.............. 900
> | |    User................ "SAP_PERF000"
> | |    Language key........ "E"
> | |    Transaction......... "VA01 "
> | |    Transactions ID..... "4A08B9BC0C022793E10000000FD5F53D"
> | |
> | |    Program............. "SAPLV05I"
> | |    Screen.............. "RSM13000 3000"
> | |    Screen line......... 2
> |
>
> ---
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |Information on where terminated
> | |    Termination occurred in the ABAP program "SAPLV05I" - in
> "SD_PARTNER_UPDATE".                 | |    The main program was
> "RSM13000 ".
> | |
> | |    In the source code you have the termination point in line 480
> | |    of the (Include) program "LV05IU15".
> | |    The program "SAPLV05I" was started in the update system.
> | |    The termination is caused because exception "CX_SY_OPEN_SQL_DB"
> occurred in                   | |    procedure "SD_PARTNER_UPDATE"
> "(FUNCTION)", but it was neither handled locally                | |
> nor declared
> | |    in the RAISING clause of its signature.
> | |
> | |    The procedure is in program "SAPLV05I "; its source code begins
> in line                       | |    1 of the (Include program
> "LV05IU15 ".                                                        |
>
> ---
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |Source Code Extract
> |
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |Line |SourceCde
> |
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |  450|                                        POSNR = I_XVBPA-POSNR
> | |  451|                                        PARVW =
> I_XVBPA-PARVW.                              | |  452|            IF
> I_YVBPA-STCD1 <> I_XVBPA-STCD1 OR
> | |  453|                I_YVBPA-STCD2 <> I_XVBPA-STCD2 OR
> | |  454|                I_YVBPA-STCD3 <> I_XVBPA-STCD3 OR
> | |  455|                I_YVBPA-STCD4 <> I_XVBPA-STCD4 OR
> | |  456|                I_YVBPA-STCDT <> I_XVBPA-STCDT OR
> | |  457|                I_YVBPA-STKZN <> I_XVBPA-STKZN OR
> | |  458|                I_YVBPA-J_1KFREPRE <> I_XVBPA-J_1KFREPRE OR
> | |  459|                I_YVBPA-J_1KFTBUS <> I_XVBPA-J_1KFTBUS OR
> | |  460|                I_YVBPA-J_1KFTIND <> I_XVBPA-J_1KFTIND.
> | |  461|              MOVE-CORRESPONDING I_XVBPA TO WA_XVBPA3I.
> | |  462|              APPEND WA_XVBPA3I TO DA_XVBPA3I.
> | |  463|            ENDIF.
> | |  464|          ENDIF.
> | |  465|        ENDIF.
> | |  466|      WHEN UPDKZ_OLD.
> | |  467|        IF DA_VBPA-ADRDA CA GCF_ADDR_IND_COMB_MAN_OLD   OR
> | |  468|           DA_VBPA-ADRDA CA GCF_ADDR_IND_COMB_MAN_ADRC.
> | |  469|          YADR-ADRNR = DA_VBPA-ADRNR. COLLECT YADR.
> | |  470|        ENDIF.
> | |  471|        IF DA_VBPA-ADRDA CA GCF_ADDR_IND_COMB_MAN_OLD   OR
> | |  472|           DA_VBPA-ADRDA CA GCF_ADDR_IND_COMB_MAN_ADRC.
> | |  473|          XADR-ADRNR = DA_VBPA-ADRNR. COLLECT XADR.
> | |  474|        ENDIF.
> | |  475|    ENDCASE.
> | |  476|  ENDLOOP.
> | |  477|  UPDATE (OBJECT) FROM TABLE DA_XVBPAU.
> | |  478|  UPDATE VBPA3 FROM TABLE DA_XVBPA3U.
> | |  479|
> | |>>>>>|  INSERT (OBJECT) FROM TABLE DA_XVBPAI.
> | |  481|  INSERT VBPA3 FROM TABLE DA_XVBPA3I.
> | |  482|
> | |  483|  IF SY-SUBRC > 0.
> | |  484|    MESSAGE A700 WITH OBJECT SY-SUBRC DA_XVBPAI(21).
> | |  485|  ENDIF.
> | |  486|
> | |  487|* Sonderfall neue VBPA (VBPA2) für Rollen AA und AW
> | |  488|  LOOP AT I_XVBPA2.
> | |  489|    DA_VBPA2 = I_XVBPA2.
> | |  490|    CASE DA_VBPA2-UPDKZ.
> | |  491|      WHEN UPDKZ_NEW.
> | |  492|        IF DA_VBPA2-ADRDA CA GCF_ADDR_IND_COMB_MAN_OLD   OR
> | |  493|           DA_VBPA2-ADRDA CA GCF_ADDR_IND_COMB_MAN_ADRC.
> | |  494|          XADR-ADRNR = DA_VBPA2-ADRNR. COLLECT XADR.
> | |  495|        ENDIF.
> | |  496|        I_XVBPA-MANDT = SY-MANDT.
> | |  497|        IF I_XVBPA2-VBELN IS INITIAL.
> | |  498|          I_XVBPA2-VBELN = F_VBELN.
> | |  499|        ENDIF.
> |
>
> ---

Comment: Please add the header of the short dump (`ST22`)  including the source code snippet where the dump occurs.

Comment: include LV05IU15 is function module SD_PARTNER_UPDATE. Row 480 is roughly (depending on SAP release, patches etc) where inserts into table VBPA3 (tax numbers for document partners) are processed. Any user exits toying around with document partners?

Comment: @Dirk I am just starting out, not sure what you are saying...

Comment: there are user exits where you as a SAP customer can add your own code to standard SAP transactions. Usually used to make some customer requirement work. You can probably mess with the partner determination in those exits. If there is code from your company present in those exits I'd first look at those and try to find out if they do anything with the document partners (add partners, change partners). Exits for VA01 are includes MV45AFZ*

Comment: ohh got it.. No customizations done in this case, after some more investigation found that duplicate entry in oracle database was causing the problem in updating... now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It is very clear that system is trying to update with some duplicate record and hence, the update termination system is popping up.  Take the help of ABAP team and check the root cause of this issue.  Also if there is any customization involved in sale order creation process, then in that case also, this will happen.  So you have to check with ABAP team.  Alternatively, if you have login credentials for Service Marketplace, then have a look at OSS note 330904.

Answer (score 0):

There are several comments to make:

- The error is due to wanting to insert into the VBPA a record with the same primary key as another existing one. That is not possible, that's why the dump.
- Apparently the transaction records satisfactorily, but this is not the case. The saving process is performed in a later task. That's why the delay between when you exit the transaction and the popup appears
- It is very likely that the number range is configured to external (that is why it enables the field entry). If so, it would only let you record the first time with the field empty, and the subsequent ones would give an error.
- Verify the existence of a record with an empty VBELN key in the VBPA through SE16.